# Project Deployment and Running Error in Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets

When I am Deploying my project war file named ict-ipr.cdac.in.war in webapps folder it is not deploying the project in webapps folder. When I checked the server logs for error this is the log:

```
Jun 11, 2014 1:36:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: E:\Tomcat7.0\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\PHP\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin
Jun 11, 2014 1:36:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 11, 2014 1:36:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8010"]
Jun 11, 2014 1:36:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1077 ms
Jun 11, 2014 1:36:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 11, 2014 1:36:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Jun 11, 2014 1:36:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor E:\Tomcat7.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\ict-ipr.cdac.in.xml
Jun 11, 2014 1:37:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.eclipse.org/birt/taglibs/birt.tld is already defined
Jun 11, 2014 1:37:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jun 11, 2014 1:37:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/ict-ipr.cdac.in] startup failed due to previous errors
Jun 11, 2014 1:37:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory E:\Tomcat7.0\webapps\docs
Jun 11, 2014 1:37:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory E:\Tomcat7.0\webapps\examples
Jun 11, 2014 1:37:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory E:\Tomcat7.0\webapps\host-manager
Jun 11, 2014 1:37:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory E:\Tomcat7.0\webapps\IPRReports
Jun 11, 2014 1:37:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanWebXml
WARNING: Failed to process TLD with path [/birt.tld] and URI [/WEB-INF/tlds/birt.tld]
java.net.MalformedURLException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanStream(TldConfig.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanWebXml(TldConfig.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:569)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1113)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1671)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Jun 11, 2014 1:37:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory E:\Tomcat7.0\webapps\manager
Jun 11, 2014 1:37:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory E:\Tomcat7.0\webapps\ROOT_LB
Jun 11, 2014 1:37:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory E:\Tomcat7.0\webapps\TrademarkImages
Jun 11, 2014 1:37:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory E:\Tomcat7.0\webapps\TrademarkSearch
Jun 11, 2014 1:37:04 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(E:\Tomcat7.0\webapps\TrademarkSearch\WEB-INF\lib\gwt-dev-windows.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jun 11, 2014 1:37:04 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(E:\Tomcat7.0\webapps\TrademarkSearch\WEB-INF\lib\gwt-user.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Jun 11, 2014 1:37:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory E:\Tomcat7.0\webapps\~`ROOT
Jun 11, 2014 1:37:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 11, 2014 1:37:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8010"]
Jun 11, 2014 1:37:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 8996 ms
```

how to fix the problem

Comment: Check tag library of `/WEB-INF/tlds/birt.tld`, whether its contents are valid or not, as the exception saying `MalformedURLException` in the tag library file.

Comment: @suninsky: Still the problem is not solved even after adding correct entries in birt.tld and the error log is same. The main Problem is the deployment of my project(war file not extracting on tomcat restart) that is tomcat not deploying the project in webapps because of above error log.

Comment: post the web.xml section where you have defined `birt.tld`